# Kohana 3.2 reuse model to insert data

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I'm currently working on a project that uses Kohana 3.2.
I haven't used the framework so I'm kind of a "beginner" though I've been using Symfony2 for quite some time.

Let's say I have a "task". This "task" can be assigned to multiple "users" at the same time. 
This is achieved by entering the same "task" with different user_id. So I thought it shouldn't be a problem to reuse the model by simply to change the column's data and then calling `$task->create()`.

For some reason this isn't working right and the code returns:
`Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Cannot create task model because it is already loaded.`

My current code is:

```
Model:
class Model_Task extends ORM{
    protected $_table_name  = 'task';
    protected $_primary_key = 'task_id';
}

Code:
$task = ORM::factory('task');
$task->task = "some random task you need to finish.";
foreach($users as $user){
    $task->user_id=$user;
    $task->create();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or you simply can't reuse models in Kohana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same task object for all users, thus after first iteration task will be loaded after calling create method. Change your code to:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $task = ORM::factory('task');
    $task->user_id = $user;
    $task->create();
}
```

Comment: I figured that was probably the problem but I wanted to be sure. Thanks :)